# r tidypolars, no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "RPolarsDataFrame"

Tags: r

I m trying the exact example from the r tidypolars package vignette:

```
require(tidypolars)
require(polars)

mtcars |> 
  as_polars() |> 
  mutate(x = sd(mpg, na.rm = TRUE))
```

and I m getting the error:

> "Error in UseMethod("mutate") :
> no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "RPolarsDataFrame"

What is causing / the fix for this error ?

Answer (score 0):

as_polars has been deprecated and I was looking at an old vignette.
One now needs to use as_polars_df() instead of as_polars()

This now runs:

```
require(tidypolars)
require(polars)
require(tidyverse)

mtcars |> 
  as_polars_df() |> 
  mutate(x = sd(mpg, na.rm = TRUE))
```